# Can I use software made up of Python language for mobile application?

Tags: java, python

I am pursuing 7th semester btech computer science. I just want to develop a software for Mobile application and I would like to develop that software in python language instead of java. Can I proceed the software in python language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  kivy ,but it won't be as good as Android studio.
It is an open source framework.
The app will be working fine ,but won't be as a native Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can . but it is Hybrid type of App not a native one..

try [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home)

A python based framework which helps to develop Mobile App Using Python.. but it wont be like Native Android App.

**What is Kivy?**

> Kivy - Open source Python library for rapid development of
>   applications that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as
>   multi-touch apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can proceed with python using a cross-platform open source library [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home)
and the good things about this is you can run your app on any operating system.
You can learn more from [Here.](https://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/intro.html)